# Why doesn't this compute to true?

Tags: verilog

For the following code snippet in Verilog:

```
////////////////////////////

reg[0:7] fat[0:511]= {'hF8, 'hFF, 'hFF , 'hFF , 'hFF , 'hFF , 'hFF , 'hFF , hFF , 'hFF , 'h06 , 'h00 , 'h07 , 'h00 , 'h08 ... ); // resembles fat 1 region on a sd card, read using hex editor. 

reg[0:32] fat_counter2 ;
reg[0:31] music_stop_add[0:1];
reg music_counter = 0;

task stop_address;
  begin

     if((fat[fat_counter2] == 'hFF )&& (fat[fat_counter2+1] == 'hFF) && (b==0))begin  
        music_stop_add[music_counter] <= ((((fat_counter2/2)-2)*64)+509)*512; // 
         b <= 1;
      end else begin
         fat_counter2 <= fat_counter2 + 1;
  end

always @ (posedge clk_100mhz) begin

    repeat(256)begin

        stop_address;

    end
end
////////////////////////////////
```

When I search the `fat` array element for a value equal to `'hFF`, using the above expression `(fat[fat_counter2] == 'hFF)`, it never computes to true. 
However when I change it to `(fat[fat_counter2] != 'hFF)`, it becomes true for every value.

Why does this is happen?

`music_stop_add[music_counter] <= ((((fat_counter2/2)-2)*64)+509)*512; //` converts the fat counter value in sector start number in bytes which I feed to read sd card controller.

I read about initializing fat using expression = `'{}`, but it shows error because of `'`.

I'm working with vivado 2016.3 to program nexys 4

Answer (score 0):

A `reg` is initialized to x by default.  `fat_counter2` is x, causing the `if` clause to evaluate to false.  Prove this to yourself by adding this `$display` to your task:

```
task stop_address;
    begin
        $display("fat_counter2=%x fat[fat_counter2]=%x", fat_counter2, fat[fat_counter2]);
        if((fat[fat_counter2] == 'hFF )&& (fat[fat_counter2+1] == 'hFF) && (b==0))begin
```

You need to initialize fat_counter2 somehow.